# How to say one person does not share another person's fascination with either of two topics (using "neither...nor")?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, neither-nor

A is fascinated with reading and writing.
B is not.

This is the sentence structure I want to use but I'm not sure if it is possible:

"B shares A's fascination with neither reading nor writing."

This sounds as if we are talking about sharing one object with another, like B sharing A's toys with neither Jack nor Jill.

So is there a way to use this sentence structure or have to break them up?

thanks

Comment: No, it does not work as you have written it. And there is no need to use it here> X does not share Y's fascination with A and B. No need to get one's knickers in a twist.

Comment: looks as if A is fascinated with neither-reading-nor-writing and B agrees.

Comment: @Lambie, if you say that, B could still be fascinated with one of them.

Comment: maybe swap _with_ and _neither_

Answer (score 1):

> This sounds as if we are talking about sharing one object with
>   another.

I disagree. I think the meaning is really clear. But if you really want to avoid using "share" (which I wouldn't), you can say simply:

> B doesn't have the same fascination for reading and writing as (does)
>   A (does).

(does) can be elided completely or placed before or after A.

or using "share":

> B doesn't share A's fascination with reading and writing.

If you really want to use the structure "neither" "nor", then:

> Unlike A, B has a fascination for neither reading nor writing.

or simpler

> Unlike A, B doesn't have any fascination with reading or writing.

or more loosely (allowing more leeway from your original sentence):

> Unlike A, B is uninterested in reading and writing.

or

> Unlike A, B is not an avid/enthusiastic reader and writer.

or quite longer and unnecessarily wordier:

> B doesn't have the same interests as A insofar as B doesn't enjoy
>   reading and writing.

or separate completely:

> A has a fascination with reading and writing; B however doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

This might change the structure more than you are looking for, but how bout this:

"B shares neither of A's fascination with reading nor writing."

Comment: That's not grammatical. Kindly reread your sentence.

Answer (score -1):

I found the sentence as presented in the question to be clear enough.
People don't share fascination the way they share toys,
and neither reading nor writing can share fascination with anyone,
so there's no temptation to misidentify the entities among whom the fascination could have been shared.

Another possible wording is,

> B shares neither A's fascination with reading nor with writing.

Comment: could you replace "with reading" with "for reading"?

Comment: I wouldn't use "for" with "fascination." But there may also be a better word than "fascination."

Comment: The sentence as presented was not grammatical.